# How do I find the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z^2 - 4}$ at $z = 2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> How do I find the Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z^2 - 4}$ at $z = 2$?

Can anyone help me out with this? I used partial fraction decomposition and got the $\frac{1}{4}$ part of it, just don't understand the rest. I think I may be treating to much like an infinite series

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/358840/28900).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for $z\neq\pm 2$ we can write $$\frac1{z+2}=\cfrac1{z-2+4}=\frac1{4}\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(-\frac{z-2}{4}\right)}$$ and $$\frac1{z+2}=\cfrac1{z-2+4}=\frac1{z-2}\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(-\frac{4}{z-2}\right)}.$$

Now, one of these can be expanded as a multiple of a geometric series in the annulus $|z-2|>4$ and the other can be expanded as a multiple of a geometric series in the annulus $0<|z-2|<4$. That is, we will use the fact that $$\frac1{1-w}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty w^k$$ whenever $|w|<1$. You should figure out which annulus works for which rewritten version, and find the respective expansions in both cases. That will give you two *different* Laurent expansions of your function, valid in two different annuli.

Comment: Fantastic answer, but is there anyway you can go a little more in depth? :x I'm still kind of confused as to how I would approach the rest

Comment: @SavageHenry: You've already seen that $$\frac1{z^2-4}=\frac14\left(\frac1{z-2}-\frac1{z+2}\right),$$ yes? For example, then, we have in the appropriate annulus that $$\begin{align}\frac1{z+2} &= \frac1{z-2}\cdot\cfrac1{1-\left(-\frac4{z-2}\right)}\\ &= \frac1{z-2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac4{z-2}\right)^k\\ &= \frac1{z-2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^k}{(z-2)^k}\\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^k}{(z-2)^{k+1}}\\ &= \frac1{z-2}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-4)^k}{(z-2)^{k+1}}.\end{align}$$ (cont'd)

Comment: From that, we find that $$\begin{align}\frac1{z-2}-\frac1{z+2} &= -\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-4)^k}{(z-2)^{k+1}}\\ &= \frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-4)^{k+1}}{(z-2)^{k+1}}\\ &= \frac14\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-4)^k}{(z-2)^k},\end{align}$$ and so $$\frac1{z^2-4} = \frac1{16}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-4)^k}{(z-2)^k}$$ in that annulus. We proceed in a similar fashion with the other expression in its annulus. I leave it to you to determine which annulus works for which expression, but as a hint, note that $$\left|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\right|<1$$ if and only if $$|z_1|<|z_2|.$$